# Findbugs: ignore some missing classes but report others

Tags: findbugs

Using findbugs I get the following:

```
The following classes needed for analysis were missing:
  foo.bar.Class1
  foo.bar.Class2
```

I know why these classes are missing, and I'm fine with it.  Since I'm using this via ant, I could use the `quietErrors` parameter, but

1. It would also quiet "serious analysis errors", which I'd want to know about.
2. If, in the future, there winds up being other missing classes, I want to be told about it so I can determine if I *do* mind those other  classes being missing.

So, is there any way to tell findbugs to not inform me about those specific classes being missing, but still tell me about other missing classes?  I tried to use an exclude filter to exclude the classes of mine which reference the missing classes, but 1) that doesn't work, and 2) even it did work, I don't want to exclude entire classes from analysis just to avoid those warning messages.

Comment: Did you find any solution? Having the same problem.

Comment: @CLOVIS Sorry, never found anything.