# Gradle + FindBugs, ignore "missing classes"

Tags: java, gradle, findbugs

I am using a Gradle script to build my Java project. I have the FindBugs plugin added.

I often get errors such as "The following classes needed for analysis were missing" for Java internal classes. I'm fine with them missing, since they are not what I want to test anyway.

The problem is that this is qualified as an error, which breaks Arcanist (and therefore breaks CI tests). I want to ignore this error.

Based on the [Gradle FindBugs plugin manual](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.FindBugs.html) I see the `excludeFilter` parameter which led me to [the FindBugs manual on filters](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html#d0e1930), which led me to [the list of bugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html) but I cannot find the "missing classes" on the list...

Simply put, I'm searching for a way to ignore the "The following classes needed for analysis were missing".

As a bonus, I would like to hide only the error for JDK classes and not for my own. This part was already asked by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26149462/findbugs-ignore-some-missing-classes-but-report-others), but it is unanswered as of now.

Comment: The "missing classes" is not a bug detected by the FindBugs/SpotBugs detectors, but an error thrown by FindBugs itself when it notices that its classpath is incomplete. In other words, you have a configuration error that causes an incomplete classpath.

Comment: I understand that, but it's normal. FindBugs shouldn't be analyzing the Java classes. Because it outputs in stderr, it breaks the CI.

Comment: Ok - I was just trying to point out that you must fix the classpath in order to (1) get correct analyses, and (2) get rid of those errors that rightfully break your build.